# Using iframe in windows 8 metro app

Tags: javascript, iframe, windows-8

I'm trying to use iframe in windows 8 metro style app built using java-script. iframe url is a different domain url.
The following errors I'm getting:

```
APPHOST9603: Can’t load the ActiveX plug-in
that has the class ID '{D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000}'.
Apps can't load ActiveX controls. File: www.trendstagram.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the page your are referencing in the iframe contains plugin.  You cannot display a page in a Windows Store app that contains plugins.

Comment: What do you mean by plugins, I'm using jquery and extended some funtions on that iframe page.

Comment: He means the activex control in the page you are loading into the Iframe.

Comment: Yes, does the html in www.trendstagram.com contain a plugin like Flash or some other kind of ActiveX control?

Comment: Application at trendstagram.com is purely based on HTML5

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the iframe in javascript and assigning the src property programmatically. This tends to help WinJS allow dynamic elements to be injected into your DOM.